# Создать экземпляр класса из очень разветвленной иерархии классов

Tags: java

Есть очень разветвленная иерархия классов:

```
Категория_1
 Подкатегория_1_1
  подподкатегория_1_1_1
  подподкатегория_1_1_2
  подподкатегория_1_1_3
 Подкатегория_1_2
  подподкатегория_1_2_1
  подподкатегория_1_2_2
Категория_2
 Подкатегория_2_1
  подподкатегория_2_1_1
  подподкатегория_2_1_2
  подподкатегория_2_1_3

и т.д...
```

Я читаю файл, в котором встречаются все уровни иерархии в текстовом виде и надо создавать именно этот класс.

Как это лучше делать? Неужели писать `switch` на 100500 вариантов классов?
(Хотелось бы без рефлексии обойтись)

Comment: порождающие паттерны проектирования в помощь...

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович они на входе берут строку и из нее с помощью `switch` (или недайбог `if`) создают класс. Я хотел бы без этих 100-этажных конструкций.

Comment: Если этот свитч в фабричном методе, а метод, как правило, в супеклассе самого верхнего уровня, то все не так страшно. метод всегда созздает нужный объеткт , приводит его  суперклассу и возвращает. не очень элегантно, но просто и эффективно. хуже, когда эти самые условия размазаны по всему коду. вот это беда, потому как в этом случае код не рефакторится и не расширяется в принципе.  в любом случае вам нужно что-то, что посмотрит на условие и создаст экземпляр класса.

Comment: можете посмотреть в сторону АОП. сделать свою аннотацию с аргументом, в котором прописывается ключевое слово из текстового файла, обозначающее необходимость создания именно этого класса. тогда аннотации будут служит скрытыми "условиями". более элегантно, но менее наглядно. к тому же для универсальности без рефлексионного подхода не обойтись. можно пойти "спринговым" путем, имитируя контейнер, возвращать либо синглтон, если это допустимо, либо клон.

Comment: зачем таким вопросам минусы ставить? львиная доля программистов (далеко не джунов) разбиваются при попытках создать экземпляры класса , а о порождающих паттернах слышно только на собеседованиях. создание объекта - это самая глубокая яма ооп, потому как для того, чтобы прочувствовать все прелести полиморфизма, надо сначала создать объект, привести его к суперклассу, и "кривое" создание этих самых экземпляров может сделать код еще хуже процедурного. вопрос хороший и заслуживает внимания!

Comment: Если подкатегорич является категорией, то можно создать класс, который ссылается на самого себя.

Comment: @Roman C переведи (с)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какого-то универсального или магического способа создавать классы без явного описания кого мы хотим "породить" нету(за исключением, возможно, каких-то манипуляций через рефлексию, но сама идея об этом уже выглядит как `overengeneering`. Как минимум один раз надо будет описать в фабрике классы, которые она может создавать. Самый популярный и простой пример порождающего паттерна, это [Abstract Factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm).